# Backbone.js `listento` not firing for a filtered collection

Tags: backbone.js

`listento` only fires for the global collection, not the collection I am passing to the view when it's created.

For instance:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(notes, "add", this.test);  // <--- THIS FIRES
    this.listenTo(this.collection, "add", this.test); // <-- THIS DOES NOT FIRE
  },

  test: function() {
    console.log('model added to collection')
  }
});
```

I am passing in the filtered collection like so when creating the view:

```
var notesFilteredByGroup = notes.filter_group(123);
var myView = new MyView({
  collection: notesFilteredByGroup
});
```

And here is the `Notes` collection:

```
Notes = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '/notes',

  model: Note,

  filter_group: function(groupNum) {
    filtered = this.filter(function(note) {
      return note.get('groupNum') === groupNum;
    });
    return new Notes(filtered);
  }
});
```

When I submit a new note, it updates the global collection just fine. How do I tell the `notesFilteredById` or `this.collection` to listen for added models?

EDIT:

Added requested code, changed some variable names to make question clearer

Note submission code:

```
var AddNoteView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'div',

  template: _.template( AddNoteTemplate ),

  events: {
    'click #noteSubmitButton': 'submit'
  },

  initialize: function() {
    this.render();
  },

  render: function() {
    var template = this.template( this.model.toJSON() );
    this.$el.html(template);
    return this;
  },

  submit: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var newNote = {
      text: $('#text').val(),
      groupNum: $('#groupNum').val(),
    };

    this.collection.create(newNote, {wait: true});
  }
});
```

Instantiating AddNoteView:

```
var notes = new Notes;
notes.fetch();
var addNoteView = new AddNoteView({
  collection: notes
});
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you add to the collection

Comment: What does `this.collection` correspond to in `AddNoteView `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose your `notes` global collection when initialized looks like this

```
var notes = new Notes();
```

So this is passed over to different views.

But when you are filtering the collection

```
   var notesFilteredById = notes.filter_id(123);

   ...
   return new Notes(filtered);
```

You are returning a **new notes** collection..

This creates a new instance which do not have the same bindings as the global `notes.`

So for that to work you have to explicitly add the model created to the filtered collection as well.

Something like this

```
// You need to pass that into the view
var addNoteView = new AddNoteView({
  collection: notes,
  filteredCollection : notesFilteredByGroup
});
```

In the view you need to add that explicitly to the other collection

```
var AddNoteView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'div',

  template: _.template( AddNoteTemplate ),

  events: {
    'click #noteSubmitButton': 'submit'
  },

  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', addToCollection);
    this.render();
  },

  render: function() {
    var template = this.template( this.model.toJSON() );
    this.$el.html(template);
    return this;
  },
  addToCollection : function(model) {
      // Need to add to the other collection.
      this.options.filteredCollection.add(model);
  },
  submit: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var newNote = {
      text: $('#text').val(),
      groupNum: $('#groupNum').val(),
    };

    this.collection.create(newNote, {wait: true});
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. I somehow thought the changes were automatically pushed to the filtered collection.

Comment: @EvanEmolo.. Glad to have helped :)